# How to extract a perticular data from xml whole output data in C++

Tags: c++, c, xml, xml-parsing, barcode

I have a C++ function which prints whole xml output data on console. This data has many elements. I want to print particular element on the console.

My function looks like below:

```
 void SampleEventListner::OnBarcodeEvent(short int eventType, std::string & pscandata){
    cout << pscandata << endl;
}
```

This above code is printing output like the attached photo. Out of many elements i need to print only datalabel. How can we do this?. Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to use [pugixml](https://pugixml.org/); small lightweight and fast.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "pugixml.hpp"

std::string XML = "<outArgs>\
  <scannerID>1</scannerID>\
  <arg-xml>\
    <scandata>\
      <modelnumber>DS9308-SR00004ZZWW</modelnumber>\
      <serialnumber>19361523701373 </serialnumber>\
      <datalabel>0x68 0x74 0x68 0x74 0x68 0x74 0x68 0x74 0x68 0x74 0x68 0x74 0x68 0x74</datalabel>\
      <rawdata>0x00 0x01 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x01</rawdata>\
    </scandata>\
  </arg-xml>\
</outArgs>";

void PrintTag(std::string &pscandata)
{
  pugi::xml_document DOM = pugi::xml_document();
  pugi::xml_parse_result result = DOM.load_string(pscandata.c_str(), pugi::parse_default);
  if (result)
    std::cout << DOM.select_node("//datalabel").node().first_child().value() << "\n";
  else
    std::cout << "Error parsing XML. Offset:" << result.offset;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  PrintTag(XML);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yoy may do it with open source [tinyxml2](http://leethomason.github.io/tinyxml2/) library.

Comment: can i print to console?